# QAbstractTableModel as a model for one QTableView and few QListViews

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt, pyqt4

Salut, community!

Briefly.

I wrote usual model over `QAbstractTableModel` and using it in usual way for `QTableView`. But I think I need to use some columns of this model for the few QListViews in `QWizard` to fill main table in the right way (for user).

For example: use the column2 as the `QListView`'s model on the page1 of the wizard; column3 for page2 for its `QListView` etc.

Please, help me to understand just two things:

1. Am I on the right way?
2. If yes then how can I make it simply and explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `QTableModel` as the model for each `QListView`, and use `QListView.setModelColumn` to choose which column they each display.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works and I'd missed that method while reading docs. For other guys: it working *AFTER* setting model to the view.

Comment: @Крайст Yes, the column number is tested against the column count of the model, so if there is no model set yet, `setModelColumn` does nothing.

Comment: Thanks. And if I will use one model for a few views **even in wizard** - is this correct or not?

Comment: You can use one model in as many views as you want, wherever they are (as long as the model isn't deleted).